# Find $f$ such that $(f(x)-f(y))\left( f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) -f(\sqrt{xy})\right) =0,\forall x,y \in (0,\infty).$

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

Find all continuous function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$(f(x)-f(y))\left( f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) -f(\sqrt{xy})\right) =0,\forall x,y \in (0,\infty).$$

My try: Assume $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$(f(x)-f(y))\left( f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) -f(\sqrt{xy})\right) =0,\forall x,y \in [0,\infty).$$

By continuity of $f$ and replace $y$ by $0$, I can prove that $f=C$. But I have no idea for this case.

Comment: Hint: you could use Cauchy inequality to $x + y$ , you know that $\frac{x + y}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy}$

Comment: So the equation will be then $ x = y $, so you could finish it

Comment: have you see if your function $f$ have a continuous prolongation at $0$ ?

Comment: Same questions on MSE: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740195/229831), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3658087/229831); on MO: [3](https://mathoverflow.net/q/269064/76416); on AOPS: [4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1224690p6149915).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f(x) = f(y)$ or $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) = f(\sqrt{xy})$, find $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740127/if-fx-fy-or-f-fracxy2-f-sqrtxy-find-f)